# How to export apache ssl certificate to windows

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, openssl, trusted-root-certificates

I have configured a web server using ubunto and apache. I use it for local testing so I installed self-signed snake-oil certificate. I want to export the snake-oil certificate and add it to my testing windows client trust store. To export the certificate, I used the following command in the apache server:
I navigated to this path where I can list the snake-oil certificate. I see it in .pem format in this name: `ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` in this path: `/etc/ssl/certs$` then I used this command:

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -out ssl-cert-snakeoil.pfx
```

But the terminal cursor is just blinking as if it is waiting me to write on the file until I click -c to exit.

How can I export my apache server certificate so that I can add it to my Windows trust store.

P.S. This is a testing environment exercise. I am aware of that it is self-signed and the consequences of adding it in the Windows trust store.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the PEM file across to your Windows client and change the file extension to either `.crt` or `.cer`.  Double click on the file and Windows will ask if you want to install it.